# How to save result of search in DB to show it many times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

Let's imagine I have Articles in my system. I can show list of Articles based on search query which includes date ranges, category or few categories, tag or few tags, author or few authors.
So I need to show filtered list of Articles to user and give him a possibility to copy link to this list and share.
But in my case the link have to be unique hash, like this: mysite.com/articles/hsdjfh7yasdfhkfuh7sdfhidsfhkd

Do I have to store it in DB to provide this functionality? If yes - how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an encryption/decryption system to generate the hash: you encrypt the search query parameters to create the hash, and you decrypt the hash when you receive it from mysite.com/articles/hsdjfh7yasdfhkfuh7sdfhidsfhkd to retrieve the search params and regenerate the list of articles.

Look at the [crypt](http://crypt.rubyforge.org/installation.html) gem for some encryption/decryption algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

I think in this case you need to use params in your URL to store the search query so that you can pass the results around, so your url might look like ...

```
mysite.com/articles/?=&cats=2,3&tags=atag,anothertag
```